# convert javascript replace to php preg_replace or str_replace

Tags: php, javascript, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I have the two javascript replace commands which work pefectly. I need to make them work in PHP.

```
var body = body.replace(/\n\n<blockquote>/g, '<blockquote>');
var body = body.replace(/<\/blockquote>\n\n/g, '<\/blockquote>');
```

I have tried many, many different regex possibilites and many str_replace's but all of them fail. What I thought would work is below, but they do not:

```
$body = preg_replace('/\n+<blockquote>/gi', '<blockquote>', $body);
$body = preg_replace('/</blockquote>\\n+/gi', '</blockquote>', $body);

$body = str_replace( "\n\n<blockquote>", "<blockquote>", $body);
$body = str_replace( "<blockquote>\n\n", "</blockquote>", $body);
```

Basically, I just need to remove the two newlines which surround the blockquote tags. Yes, I have confirmed they are new lines and not carriage returns.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are the str_replace working? they seem fine to me

Comment: unfortunately, no they are not ...strange behavior for sure ...I've been working on this for way too many hours. The newlines are actually added with a str_replace in another section of code, but later in another section of code after the user views it, I need to remove the newlines. Sounds simple, but no clue why simple isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code is correct and the problem might be the presence of characters other then the newlines after or before your tag. The `\n` might be there but i am pretty sure you might have some spaces in there too.

for debugging purposes trying doing this

- Replace your new lines

  $body = str_replace("\n", '--newline--', $body);
- replace your white spaces.

  $body = str_replace(" ", '--whitespace--', $body);
- echo the body

  echo $body;

if you have anything there, you will notice it now.
Good luck :)

Comment: When I ran the code you provided on some sample text, the --whitespace-- was displayed between each word ...so that worked ...but the --newline-- was never displayed. I tried changing it to \r and results were the same ...some how the new lines are being added and they are not \n or \r. Thanks for idea o checking the newlines in this manner ....at least it eliminates some of the possibilities.

Comment: one last thing, when newlines are not `\n` they may be `\r\n`

Comment: I discovered the reason I cannot remove the new lines is the editor (ckeditor) is adding them after the fact. So, now I just need to find a way to correct the behavior of the editor. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a `/` in the last call:

```
$body = str_replace("</blockquote>\n\n", "</blockquote>", $body);
```

With this fix, your str_replace solution should work. I notice that you use the `i` modifier in your regular expressions. Maybe you want to use [str_ireplace](http://php.net/str_ireplace) to make an case-insensitive replacement.

Comment: Then your code is working. Maybe the input is in fact changed in some manner, for example with spaces between the newlines and similar?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too, but when I revert back to the javacript, it works perfectly. The text is coming from a textarea and is then sent by jquery to a PHP file. Currently, the newlines are stripped via javascript before it goes to to the php file, but would like to get the newlines stripped in the php file, per client request.

Comment: Where and how did you check that your newlines are not carriage returns? On the server just before your replace code, or in the client? If you run a Windows server, the linefeeds may have changed.

Comment: unix server ...the newlines were added by a previous str_replace